# how to return list type with filter in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, case-when

I expect my query would give me the type list when at each columns give YES.

The table look this:

```
a      b     c     d     no
yes   null  yes   null   1
null  yes   yes   null   2
yes   null  null  yess   3
```

the desired result from the query:

```
no   type
1     a
1     c
2     b
2     c
3     a
3     d
```

how should I write my query in order to get my expected result?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either look into [`pivot tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) or union with multiple queries:

```
SELECT no,'a' AS type FROM t WHERE a IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT no,'b' FROM t WHERE b IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT no,'c' FROM t WHERE c IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT no,'d' FROM t WHERE d IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY no,type
```

**EDIT** (see comments):

```
SELECT no,'a' AS type FROM t WHERE a = 'yes'
UNION SELECT no,'b' FROM t WHERE b = 'yes'
UNION SELECT no,'c' FROM t WHERE c = 'yes'
UNION SELECT no,'d' FROM t WHERE d = 'yes'
ORDER BY no,type;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4650d6ba5f486a4e3dcfe4dc3319c868)

Comment: Possibly `WHERE a = 'yes'` etc would be better.  If the value of a is 'no', I doubt whether the OP wants the result.  We do not know that the only possible values are 'yes' and null (albeit these are the only values in the sample data).

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I thought the same, but in the OP there is `yes` and `yess` (with double `s`), so I decided to go safe and catch the nulls :-D thanks for the hint

Comment: thanks! It actually supposed to be yes not yess. Is there any way to shorten the query?

Comment: @nomnom3214 there is certainly a shorter way to solve this, but much more complex (take a look at pivot tables / crosstab). For such a simple use case I wouldn't bother with other crosstable at all, of course considering performance and the amount of columns you have ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use unnest:

```
WITH cte as
(SELECT no, 
unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) as type,
unnest(array[a, b, c, d]) as colvalue
from abcdtypes)
SELECT no, type 
FROM cte 
where colvalue = 'yes'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

It works and is arguably more elegant.  But I would only do something like this, if there were very many columns.  For the four in your example, I too would side with Jim Jones.